# css: appearing background-colored block when hovered / javascript: fadein&out the background-colored block

Tags: javascript, css, hover

Since 3 weeks, I've been working hard on a page and right now, I was going to add a background-colored block (outside and inside) with an fadein&out effect with javascript.

So first thing first, I've wanted to create the background border, i wanted it to appear when i hover on one of my images, but i get stuck here. I thought if i add something like :

```
.saintemarie{
border: 20px solid #FFF;
left:700px;
top:500px;
overflow:hidden;
display:none;
}
```

it actually messes up my pages and remove all my images [image: before]

```js
function mouseOver() {

  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('lycee');
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].style.opacity = "0";

  }
  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('formations');
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].style.opacity = "0";
  }
}


function thirdOver() {

  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('college');
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].style.opacity = "0";
  }
  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('formations');
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].style.opacity = "0";
  }
}

function fifthOver() {

  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('lycee');
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].style.opacity = "0";
  }
  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('college');
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].style.opacity = "0";
  }
}

function mouseOut() {
  var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].style.opacity = "1";
  }
}
```

```css
.college .image {
  left: 100px;
  top: 475px;
  position: absolute
}

.college:hover .imagefirst {
  opacity: 0.2;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  transition: border-color 2s;
}

.lycee .spanthird::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: -20px;
  border: 20px solid red;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}

.lycee .spanthird:hover::before {
  opacity: 1
}

.lycee .spanthird::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  /* semi transparent red */
  transition: opacity 2s;
}

.lycee .spanthird:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.lycee .spanthird {
  position: relative;
}

.college .imagesecond {
  width: 550px;
  height: 900px;
  transform: translate(-110px, 500px);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.college:hover>.imagesecond {
  transform: translate(-110px, -500px);
}

.lycee .image {
  left: 700px;
  top: 500px;
  position: absolute
}

.lycee .imagefourth {
  width: 537px;
  height: 600px;
  transform: translate(-160px, 500px);
  transition: transform 20s ease-in-out 0.1s;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.lycee:hover>.imagefourth {
  transform: translate(-160px, -325px);
}

.formations .image {
  left: 1250px;
  top: 510px;
  position: absolute;
}

.formations .imagesixth {
  width: 550px;
  height: 900px;
  transform: translate(-100px, 400px);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden
}

.formations:hover>.imagesixth {
  transform: translate(-173px, -600px);
}

body {
  background: url("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150") 33em 0% fixed no-repeat;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgb(0, 85, 170);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="csspp.css" />

  <title> sainte marie </title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="saintemarie">
    <a href="college/collegesaintemarie.html">
      <div onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()" class="college">
        <span class="spanfirst"> <img class="image imagefirst" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" /></span>
        <span class="spansecond"><img class="image imagesecond" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"/></span>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="lycee/lyceesaintemarie.html">
      <div onmouseover="thirdOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()" class="lycee">
        <span class="spanthird"><img class="image imagethird" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" /></span>
        <span class="spanfourth"><img class="image imagefourth" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" /></span>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="c&formation/c&fsaintemarie.html">
      <div onmouseover="fifthOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()" class="formations">
        <span class="spanfifth"><img  class="image imagefifth" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" /></span>
        <span class="spansixth"><img class="image imagesixth" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" /></span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <script src="scripts/javascriptpp.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

,for what i was going to do with javascript, i've wanted to create a Fadein/Fadeout effect with opacity and the background colored border that i have added so that when i hover into one of my pictures it creates a "colored" shadows which makes you focus less on the background but more on the image.

as for my javascript code i was going to add a classname or a tagname to my div and make something that looks like

```
 var el = document.getElementById("div1");

 function fadeIn(el) {
   el.style.opacity = 1;


   var tick = function() {
     el.style.opacity = +el.style.opacity - 0.01;


     if (+el.style.opacity > 0) {
       (window.requestAnimationFrame && requestAnimationFrame(tick)) || 
 setTimeout(tick, 16)
     }
   };

   tick();
 }

 fadeIn(el);
```

can you clarify if im wrong with my javascript? or that i can fuse it with my orther lines of codes? im half lost since my problem comes from the background border

also i cannot use jQuery for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fade a border is really simply, and here is a sample you can apply to your code.

To not make the image bounce when hover, a transparent border is applied already and on hover it fades to red.

```css
img {
  margin: 20px;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  transition: border-color 2s;
}

img:hover {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/150" alt="">
```

---

Another option is to use a pseudo element and a wrapper around the image, like this, where one also can use a i.e. semitransparent background etc.

```css
img {
  display: block;
}
span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}
span::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px; left: -20px;
  right: -20px; bottom: -20px;
  border: 20px solid red;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}
span:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 0;
  right: 0; bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);       /* semi transparent red */
  transition: opacity 2s;
}
span:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150" alt="">
</span>
```

---

Update based on a comment

Here is a simplified version of your code base, where I moved the `position: absolute;` from the image to the `span`,

```css
.lycee .spanthird {
  position: absolute;      /* moved from ".lycee .image" */
  left: 100px;             /* moved from ".lycee .image" */
  top: 100px;              /* moved from ".lycee .image" */
}

.lycee .image {
  display: block;          /* to avoid white space */
}

.lycee .spanthird::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: -20px;
  border: 20px solid red;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}

.lycee .spanthird:hover::before {
  opacity: 1
}

.lycee .spanthird::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  /* semi transparent red */
  transition: opacity 2s;
}

.lycee .spanthird:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="lycee/lyceesaintemarie.html">
      <div class="lycee">
        <span class="spanthird"><img class="image imagethird" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" /></span>
      </div>
    </a>
```

Comment: can i make to have not only the border red but inside of the border too? i may have explained it wrong but when i said a background-colored border, it is more of a colored block that i can change size and position as long as it doesn't messes up with my page

Comment: @souzouker I added a second sample, where you can color it how you want, and when done like this, with absolute positioning, it won't affect surrounding elements

Comment: oh! now im quite curious, is it possible to change the height speciafically to the semi-transparant red? like if i want to go all the way up with it? changing his size but not the size of the image ?

Comment: @souzouker Yes, will add one more sample using the other pseudo

Comment: @souzouker Updated my second sample showing how to have 2 different effects, one with each pseudo.

Comment: i edited my lines while trying what you've showed to me but i didn't make it to work . thought it should be working , can you look into it?

Comment: @souzouker The image div wrapper need to have a position, i.e. `.lycee { position: relative;}` ... and I can't see either of your images, only the background image, 350x150, so to help more, you need to make them visible for me

Comment: i can see the border appearing at the top left

Comment: @souzouker Ahh, now I see. You can't set image to absolute and re-position it like that, you have to wrap each image with a span, like I did, and then position the span instead. When done like this the `lycee` element collapse to nothing, hence the border shows up in the upper left corner

Comment: i've added a span with a class name for each of every image i use except the background image, i changed my css so that it use the span instead of the image class name but it didn't change or should i have tried to put left/top lines of code?

Comment: @souzouker I added a 3rd sample, with code from your original code base.

Comment: i think i may be getting out of the subject, even thought the way you have showed LGSon im gonna try a more simplified way. thank you LGSon i may try what you taught mee later in my days

Comment: @souzouker That is perfectly fine :) ... and as I actually provided a working solution I would appreciate if you accepted my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS solution if that's allowed.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img:hover {
  animation: setborder 1s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes setborder {
  0% {
    border: medium solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
  }
  50% {
    border: medium solid rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
  }
  100% {
    border: medium solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="saintemarie">
  <a href="college/collegesaintemarie.html">
    <div class="college">
      <img class="image imagefirst" src="http://via.placeholder.com/196x175" />
      <img class="image imagesecond" src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x440" />
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="lycee/lyceesaintemarie.html">
    <div class="lycee">
      <img class="image imagethird" src="http://via.placeholder.com/183x140" />
      <img class="image imagefourth" src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x440" />
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="c&formation/c&fsaintemarie.html">
    <div class="formations">
      <img class="image imagefifth" src="http://via.placeholder.com/172x153" />
      <img class="image imagesixth" src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x440" />
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```